# Describe the right cosets of $H$ in $G$ and find $|G : H|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=(\Bbb Z, +)$ and let n be a positive integer. Let $H = n\Bbb Z= \{na : a \in \Bbb Z\}$. We know that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Describe the right cosets of $H$ in $G$ and find $|G : H|$.  Since $\Bbb Z$ is an infinite group does that mean there is an infinte number of right cosets and hence $|G : H|= \infty$.  I am not sure I am new to the concept of right cosets

Comment: Note that $G$ is Abelian.  $G$ is infinite, but so is $H$.  Are you familiar with $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since $\Bbb Z$ is an infinite group does that mean there is an infinte number of right cosets.

No.

The construction you're looking for is $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. The right cosets of $H$ are $$H+a=\{b\in \Bbb Z\mid (a-b)\in H\}$$ and $[G:H]=n$. The latter is because the cosets partition $\Bbb Z$ into remainders upon division by $n$.